# Python Dictionary replace value and save in dict

Tags: python, dictionary

My dictionary values are strings that are supposed to have `'|x'` at the end of each term. Some strings contain many terms and they are separated by a `space`.

I am trying to remove terms in the values that do not have `'|x'` but the dictionary is not saving the new value.

```
d={'food': u'burger|x fries|x soda pie|x', 'transport': u'bus|x', 'animal': u'cat|x'}

for k,v in d.iteritems():
    for t in v.split(' '):
        if '|x' in v:
            v=v.replace(t,'')
```

output:

```
d
{'food': u'burger|x fries|x soda pie|x', 'animal': u'cat|x', 'transport': u'bus|x'}
```

output i want:

```
{'food': u'burger|x fries|x pie|x', 'animal': u'cat|x', 'transport': u'bus|x'}
```

Why didnt the value get replaced?

Comment: What output do you want, because I don't understand your question.

Comment: please see my edit

Comment: The value didn't get replaced because you never replaced it. You need `d[k]=v` after your `v=v.replace(...)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're only creating a new string and not updating the value(s) in the dict.

You can instead remove those items using a dictionary comprehension:

```
d = {'food': u'burger|x fries|x soda pie|x', 'transport': u'bus|x', 'animal': u'cat|x'}
d = {k: ' '.join(i for i in v.split() if i.endswith('|x')) for k, v in d.iteritems()}
print d
# {'food': u'burger|x fries|x pie|x', 'transport': u'bus|x', 'animal': u'cat|x'}
```

Note that `split()` can replace `split(' ')` in this context.

Comment: Small note - if OP is using Python 2 (which is likely from the call to `iteritems()`), it may also be better to use `iteritems()` here in the dict comprehension.

Comment: Another minor point - since each term must _end_ with `|x`, use `i.endswith('|x')` instead of `'|x' in i` (which would match anywhere within the term).

Answer (score 1):

## Input

```
d = {'food': u'burger|x fries|x soda pie|x', 'transport': u'bus|x', 'animal': u'cat|x'}
```

## Code

```
for (i, j) in d.iteritems():
    x = j.split()
    for k in x:
        if not k.endswith('|x'):            
            x.remove(k)
    d[i] = " ".join(x)
```

## Output

```
d = {'food': u'burger|x fries|x pie|x', 'transport': u'bus|x', 'animal': u'cat|x'}
```

Comment: You did not update the value in the dictionary to get your expected results.

Comment: This solution is really basic and simple to understand. You can tweak it the more to make it more advanced.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to a dictionary comprehension is to update the dictionary *in place*. This might be better for very large dictionaries because the dict comprehension produces a second dictionary:

```
d = {'food': u'burger|x fries|x soda pie|x', 'transport': u'bus|x', 'animal': u'cat|x'}

for k in d:
    terms = d[k].split()
    d[k] = ' '.join(term for term in terms if term.endswith('|x'))
```

Or shoehorning it into one operation:

```
for k in d:
    d[k] = ' '.join(term for term in d[k].split() if term.endswith('|x'))
```